# Difference In Phpmyadmin Mysql web client and Terminal client

Tags: mysql, import, triggers, phpmyadmin, procedure

I got problem **(#2006 Mysql server gone away)** with mysql while connecting and performing some operations through web browser.

**Operation Listed below:**

1. When Executing big procedure
2. Importing database dump
3. When Access some particular tables It immediately throws "Server gone away".

Refer this question for Scenarios: [Record Not Inserted - #2006 Mysql server gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464939/record-not-inserted-2006-mysql-server-gone-away)

Note : The above operations are works fine when I perform through terminal.

I tried some configuration as googing stated. That is set wait_timeout, max_allowed_packet. I checked for the bin_log but it is not available.
But the issues will not rectified.

1. What is the problem & How can I figure out & fix the issue?
2. what is the different between access phpmyadmin mysql server from web browser and terminal?
3. Where I can find the mysql server log file?

Note: If you know about any one of the above questions. Please post here. It would be helpful to trace.

Please help me to figure this out..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Below are answer for question**

1. From my research the problem is that browser have some limit to disconnect the connection i.e timeout connection. So that the above problem raised.

   To resolve this problem

   1. Go to /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin and open config.inc.php
   2. add the command **$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;**
   3. Restart the xamp server. Now you can perform any operations.

`
2. Web client is differ from terminal because Terminal client will not getting timeout. Terminal client maintain the connection till the progress completed. I recommenced to use command prompt to import/export/run process by safe way.

1. Basically phpmyadmin will not have any log file. If you wanna see warnings and error you should configure the log file.

   Configuration steps:

   1. Go to /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
   2. Add log_bin = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/filename.log
   3. Restart the xamp server. You can get the log information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Basically nothing except phpMyAdmin is limited by PHP's timeout and resource limits (limits to keep a runaway script from bogging down your entire machine for all eternity; see [the docs](https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=timeout#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems) for details of those values. In some cases, you might be authenticating through a different user account (for instance, root@localhost and root@127.0.0.1 aren't the same user), but as long as you're using a user with the same permissions the differences are minimal.
2. You can read more about logs in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html), note that "By default, no logs are enabled (except the error log on Windows)".

Comment: I am importing through root@localhost user. But I installed the same version in another machine. It works fine.